# Find div element by multiple class names?

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

`<div class="value test" />`
I'd like to identify that web element. It only has this two classes defined.
I cannot do the following as `className` does not take a space separated value. What are alternatives?

```
@FindBy(className = "value test")
@CacheLookup
private WebElement test;
```

Answer (score 188, accepted):

I don't think barak manos's answer has fully explained it.

Imagine we have few elements as the followings:

1. `<div class="value test"></div>`
2. `<div class="value test     "></div>`
3. `<div class="first value test last"></div>`
4. `<div class="test value"></div>`

How XPath matches

- Match only 1 (exact match), barak's answer

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='value test']"));
  ```
- Match 1, 2 and 3 (match class contains `value test`, class order matters)

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'value test')]"));
  ```
- Match 1, 2, 3 and 4 (as long as elements have class `value` and `test`)

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'value') and contains(@class, 'test')]"));
  ```

Also, in cases like this, Css Selector is always in favor of XPath (fast, concise, native).

- Match 1

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='value test']"));
  ```
- Match 1, 2 and 3

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class*='value test']"));
  ```
- Match 1, 2, 3 and 4

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.value.test"));
  ```

Comment: thanks for the nice explanations, it works perfectly in my selenium instance

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
test = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='value test']"));
```

Answer (score 6):

If anyone still wonders, i accomplished this by connecting the class names with dots:

Python:

```
time_element = post.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'MUxGbd.wuQ4Ob.WZ8Tjf')[0].text
```

Answer (score 2):

### Class By.ByClassName

Class [By.ByClassName](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByClassName.html#ByClassName-java.lang.String-) is defined in [By.java](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/By.java#L101) as follows:

```
/**
 * Find elements based on the value of the "class" attribute. If an element has multiple classes, then
 * this will match against each of them. For example, if the value is "one two onone", then the
 * class names "one" and "two" will match.
 *
 * @param className The value of the "class" attribute to search for.
 * @return A By which locates elements by the value of the "class" attribute.
 */
public static By className(String className) {
  return new ByClassName(className);
}
```

---

### This usecase

So as per the defination you can't pass multiple classes i.e. `value` and `test` as arguments to `@FindBy(className = "...")`. Sending multiple classes will raise an error as:

```
invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
```

---

### Solution

There are multiple approaches to solve this usecase as follows:

- If the element is uniquely identified only through the `classname` **`value`** you can use:

  ```
  @FindBy(className = "value")
  @CacheLookup
  private WebElement test;
  ```
- If the element is uniquely identified only through the `classname` **`test`** you can use:

  ```
  @FindBy(className = "test")
  @CacheLookup
  private WebElement test;
  ```
- If both the `classnames`, **`value`** and **`test`** are mandatory to identify the element, you can use [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) as follows:

  ```
  @FindBy(css  = ".value.test")
  @CacheLookup
  private WebElement test;
  ```
- As an alternative you can also use [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) as follows:

  ```
  @FindBy(xpath   = "//*[@class='value test']")
  @CacheLookup
  private WebElement test;
  ```

---

### tl; dr

[Invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted error using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528072/invalid-selector-compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-using-selenium/53536022#53536022)