# Locating label element using class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, testng

I'm trying to locate the label element and fill it with some value but I'm not able to get it. I'm using `Java`, `testNG` and `Selenium` to write the below code.

The code that I used is below

```
driver.findElement(By.className("ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched")).sendKeys("12345");
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.className("item-input-wrapper scan-input-label")).sendKeys("12345");
```

This is the details of element that I received when I inspect the element.

[image]

Comment: why are you try to change a label?

Comment: Duplicate of [Find div element by multiple class names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713280/find-div-element-by-multiple-class-names)

Comment: @ScaryWombat :) He's not. In his generosity, he just trying to send that label some keys, to see it over the winter. Surely a wombat like you can sympathise. Cheers, mate :)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi - It didn't helped in my case. I tried.

Comment: Can any one else please help me :(

Answer (score 3):

Actually selenium doesn't support to locate an element using `By.className()` **with compound class name**. You should try using `By.cssSelector()` instead to locate `<input>` element as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder = 'Scan Container Label']")).sendKeys("12345");
```

Or more specific :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder = 'Scan Container Label'][ng-model *= 'ctrl.currentValue']")).sendKeys("12345");
```

**Edited** :- If you want to locate `<label>` element using their class name try as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label.item-input-wrapper.scan-input-label"));
```

Or you can locate it also using `By.className()` with anyone if the single class name as :-

```
driver.findElement(By.className("item-input-wrapper"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually selenium doesn't support to locate an element using By.className()
You can try syntax of css with classname, css=tagname.classname

i.e.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(input.item-input-wrapper)).sendKeys("12345");
```

Comment: selenium do support `By.className()` for locating an element using its class.But the problem here it accepts only single class name.