# C# FindElement ClassName enumeration

Tags: c#, selenium

when going to the site when you go to the site, the button "Continue" can have 2 options: class="button" or class="btn". How to do a search at once for 2 classes in 1 FindElement. I do not know how it should look, but like so (schematically)

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("button" or "btn"));
```

Or easier to use if else?

```
IWebElement element18 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'button') or contains(@class, 'btn')]"));
```

Not work.

Thank you for attention

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find div element by multiple class names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713280/find-div-element-by-multiple-class-names)

Comment: No, he finds only ClassName. Xpath can not find.

Comment: Why doesn't XPath work? I mean what exception do you see, null element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If XPath doesn't work you can write something like this:

```
public IWebElement GetElements(params By[] searchBy)
{
    var list = new List<IWebElement>();
    foreach (var by in searchBy)
    {
        list.AddRange(driver.FindElements(by));              
    }
    return list.Count == 1 ? list[0] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple using a CSS selector, `".button, .btn"`, or if you want to be more specific, `"div.button, div.btn"`. The comma equates to an OR operator.