# Find by Class name command is not working

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

https://www.n11.com/telefon-ve-aksesuarlari/cep-telefonu-aksesuarlari

In this web site, I am trying to click (next page button)

I want to catch this line

```
<a href="https://www.n11.com/telefon-ve-aksesuarlari/cep-telefonu-aksesuarlari?pg=3" class="next navigation"></a>
```

I am writing this code in program

```
data=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("next navigation")
```

My question is about this problem.. it is not working

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"?

Answer (score 17):

`data=driver.find_elements_by_class_name()` accepts only single class name.

`class="next navigation"` defines two classes, `next` and `navigation`.

So you are only able to search for `next` or for `navigation` like this:

```
elementObj = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("next")
elementObj = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("navigation")
```

To find a element by multiple class names use xpath or cssSelector: [Find div element by multiple class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713280/find-div-element-by-multiple-class-names)

```
elementObj = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".next.navigation"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`By.CLASS_NAME` does not seem to work if there is `space` in the class name like in your case `"next navigation"`

Workaround should be to use `CSS_SELECTOR` instead of `CLASS_NAME` and using `.` instead of `space`

```
data = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".next.navigation")
```