# How can I know which element is clickable?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl data from this website https://www.topcv.vn/cong-ty/fpt-software/3.html, and I want to move to next page using Selenium. But when I use click() method, it just doesn't work.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-paginate btn-next" data-page="1" data-id="11111"> <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i> </a>
```

What do I do wrong?

I try using click():

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn btn-paginate btn-next').click()
```

but it just return on my command screen this:
`
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\DataPre-handle\f1.py", line 20, in <module>
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn btn-paginate btn-next').click()

`

Comment: The `class` attribute in the HTML is a **space-separated list** of classes. You use only one of those.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find by Class name command is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57766234/find-by-class-name-command-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the cocumentation of [By implementation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by) ***By.CLASS_NAME*** accepts only one classname. Passing multiple classnames will result into [invalid selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53536022/7429447).

---

Given the HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-paginate btn-next" data-page="1" data-id="11111"> 
    <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i> 
</a>
```

To click on the element to move to next page as the desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-paginate.btn-next > i"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-paginate btn-next']/i"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to click that Next button, use: `"a.btn-next"` (`By.CSS_SELECTOR`) for your selector.

If you're looking for a reusable method to help you determine if an element is clickable:

```py
def is_element_clickable(driver, selector, by="css selector"):
    """
    Returns whether the specified element selector is clickable.
    @Params
    driver - the webdriver object (required)
    selector - the locator for identifying the page element (required)
    by - the type of selector being used (Default: "css selector")
    @Returns
    Boolean (is element clickable)
    """
    try:
        element = driver.find_element(by=by, value=selector)
        if element.is_displayed() and element.is_enabled():
            return True
        return False
    except Exception:
        return False
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Selenium's `waits`. Below code will wait for `30s` to check if the element is clickable(basically it will check if its visible and enabled).

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-paginate btn-next']"))).click()
```

Or this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//a[@data-id='11111'])[2]"))).click()
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Full working code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.topcv.vn/cong-ty/fpt-software/3.html")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

# below line will close the pop-up which appears as soon the webpage is opened
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[@class='fa-solid fa-xmark']"))).click()
# below line will click on the next page button 
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-paginate btn-next']"))).click()
```

Comment: `(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn btn-paginate btn-next')` will never work, no matter how long you wait.

Comment: Yes you are right. `By.CLASS_NAME` will not work. As per question's title, I was emphasizing more on `element_to_be_clickable` feature. However, I had provided another solution too using XPATH strategy which will work. I have updated the answer and removed `CLASS_NAME` locator stretegy now.