# Match multiple class names

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Is it possible to get Selenium to match multiple class names?
For example:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('image' or 'image-large')
```

Thanks

Comment: This should be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713280/find-div-element-by-multiple-class-names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS you would do `.image, .image-large` to match elements that have either `image` class or `image-large` class.

And [Selenium has a CSS selector method](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors):

```py
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.image, .image-large')
```