# CANT SELECT DROPDOWN

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i want select li dropdown to click
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5ws1.png)

```
driver.find_element((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='ellipsis1']")).click()
```

error :

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid
> argument: 'using' must be a string

and i change the code to

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='ellipsis1']").click()
```

error :

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate  element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@class='ellipsis1']"}

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find div element by multiple class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713280/find-div-element-by-multiple-class-names)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use that one:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='ellipsis1 selectbox-item(1)']").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class,'ellipsis1')][1]").click()
```

Comment: Both cause this error "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException"

Comment: @Puleugo yes, coz we pass tuple instead of 2 arguments, I've update to code snippet