# How to get element name or id in bootstrap carousel next button for Selenium Automation?

Tags: python, selenium, bootstrap-4, automated-tests, webbrowser-control

I am trying to automate bootstrap carousel next button with **Selenium**.
The code is given as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='d:/CRD/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('file:///D:/slider/bootst.html')
button1 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "a.carousel-control")
button1.click()
```

The way I am trying to get the ID using chrome inspect element option as shown below:
[image: Inspecting carousel next button]

How can I get the next button pressed automatically using Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use other selectors like XPATH if you want, but I think you should use CSS SELECTOR for "a.right.carousel-control" not CLASS_NAME.

[More explanation on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713280/find-div-element-by-multiple-class-names)

Have a great day !