# Cannot get button element of Website in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the Selenium API and Python. Trying to get a button element of a website. The element is this:

```
<button class="bg-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-800 items-center font-semibold text-white rounded-r-md px-5 py-3" type="submit">Chat</button>.
```

My code:

```
button = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR(".flex-grow block w-full rounded-l-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-gray-600 sm:leading-6"))
```

I tried to use CSS_SELECTOR on both the element's class and type. But both don't work. They give me the error: `'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find div element by multiple class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713280/find-div-element-by-multiple-class-names)

Comment: For matching multiple classes it would look like `.flex-grow.block.w-full.etc`. The better option is to match `button[type="submit"]`. You can also test the css selector in the browser console with `document.querySelector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the correct method to find the element. I can see you are using `elements` are you using any loop ? if not than the below will work you try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[type="submit"]')
```

if you are using loop than use below

```
button = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[type="submit"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), `find_elements` first takes `By.CSS_SELECTOR` then takes css selector string. Here is the correct way of using it :

```
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "desired css selector")
```

So, why do you see `'str' object is not callable`? because you are using `By.CSS_SELECTOR` as a function and trying to pass the desired css selector to it.